# How to Keep People from Randomly Accessing Form Action Page

Tags: php, html, forms

I am creating an HTML form that references a PHP file to send an email.  However, people keep hitting the form's action page, which then sends me an email with no information filled in.  I would like to solve this by somehow protecting that action page from outside hits.

Here is my code:

HTML form:

```
<form name="homecontact" action="/admin/formactions/writequick.php" method="POST">
        <input name="name" placeholder="Name"></input>
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email"></input>
        <input name="phone" placeholder="Phone"></input>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" style="background:MidnightBlue; color:white;">
</form>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
$to      = 'myemailaddress@example.com';
$subjectadmin = 'CONTACT FORM from My Website';
$subjectuser = 'Contact Confirmation from My Website';
$name = $_POST['name'];  
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['message'];
$messageadmin = 'A customer just submitted a form on Your Website.  Here is their message:' . "\n" . "\n" . 'Name:' . '   ' . $name . "\n" . 'Email:' . '   ' . $email . "\n" . 'Phone:' . '   ' . $phone . "\n" . 'Comments:' . '   ' . $comments . "\n";
$messageuser = 'Hello,' . ' ' . $name . '!' . "\n" . "\n" . 'Thank you for contacting My Website!  We have received your contact form and we will get back to you as soon as we can.' . "\n" . "\n" . 'Just for your records, here is what you submitted to us:' . "\n" . 'Name:' . '  ' . $name . "\n" . 'Email:' . '  ' . $email . "\n" . 'Phone:' . '  ' . $phone . "\n" . 'Comments:' . '  ' . $comments . "\n" . "\n" . 'Thank you for choosing My Website!';
$headers = 'From: myotheraddress@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subjectadmin, $messageadmin, $headers);
mail($email, $subjectuser, $messageuser, $headers);
?>
```

The form works perfectly, but I just do not know how to keep people from hitting that action page, unless they go through the form.

Comment: You should be using `isset()` and `empty()` with conditional statements. Sessions and tokens would be a nice added touch.

Comment: UPDATE:  I have attempted all of the solutions on the page, but nothing is working.  I know it is me that is the problem, and not you, but does anyone have any suggestions further?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen the answer I posted? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26113089/

Comment: Yes I did.  The email still gets sent.

Comment: Did you not change the submit button with what you have now, as shown in my answer? That should not be sending mail, believe me. It should only send if the submit button was pressed from your form. I've done many of these questions before.

Comment: I did exactly what you said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62152/discussion-between-enzo-mac-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I like that, but will it still send it if only one field is blank? I don't want people to HAVE to put their contact info if they do not want to."*

Quickest fix then: name your submit button

```
<input type="submit" style="background:MidnightBlue; color:white;" name="submit">
```

and wrap your code inside a conditional statement.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    // rest of your PHP/mail code

}
```

then just use a header to redirect on mail success

```
...
mail($email, $subjectuser, $messageuser, $headers);
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
exit;
```

---

Use this in your form: (replace it with the one you have now)

```
<input type="submit" style="background:MidnightBlue; color:white;" name="submit">
```

Rewrite:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to      = 'myemailaddress@example.com';
$subjectadmin = 'CONTACT FORM from My Website';
$subjectuser = 'Contact Confirmation from My Website';
$name = $_POST['name'];  
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['message'];
$messageadmin = 'A customer just submitted a form on Your Website.  Here is their message:' . "\n" . "\n" . 'Name:' . '   ' . $name . "\n" . 'Email:' . '   ' . $email . "\n" . 'Phone:' . '   ' . $phone . "\n" . 'Comments:' . '   ' . $comments . "\n";
$messageuser = 'Hello,' . ' ' . $name . '!' . "\n" . "\n" . 'Thank you for contacting My Website!  We have received your contact form and we will get back to you as soon as we can.' . "\n" . "\n" . 'Just for your records, here is what you submitted to us:' . "\n" . 'Name:' . '  ' . $name . "\n" . 'Email:' . '  ' . $email . "\n" . 'Phone:' . '  ' . $phone . "\n" . 'Comments:' . '  ' . $comments . "\n" . "\n" . 'Thank you for choosing My Website!';
$headers = 'From: myotheraddress@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subjectadmin, $messageadmin, $headers);
mail($email, $subjectuser, $messageuser, $headers);

// redirect after mail sent
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); // modify it to your site
exit;

}

else{ echo "You can't do that from here."; }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty($_POST)) {

    // you should also validate your _POST data (email syntaxis, etc)

    $to      = 'myemailaddress@example.com';
    $subjectadmin = 'CONTACT FORM from My Website';
    $subjectuser = 'Contact Confirmation from My Website';
    $name = $_POST['name'];  
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $comments = $_POST['message'];
    $messageadmin = 'A customer just submitted a form on Your Website.  Here is their message:' . "\n" . "\n" . 'Name:' . '   ' . $name . "\n" . 'Email:' . '   ' . $email . "\n" . 'Phone:' . '   ' . $phone . "\n" . 'Comments:' . '   ' . $comments . "\n";
    $messageuser = 'Hello,' . ' ' . $name . '!' . "\n" . "\n" . 'Thank you for contacting My Website!  We have received your contact form and we will get back to you as soon as we can.' . "\n" . "\n" . 'Just for your records, here is what you submitted to us:' . "\n" . 'Name:' . '  ' . $name . "\n" . 'Email:' . '  ' . $email . "\n" . 'Phone:' . '  ' . $phone . "\n" . 'Comments:' . '  ' . $comments . "\n" . "\n" . 'Thank you for choosing My Website!';
    $headers = 'From: myotheraddress@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subjectadmin, $messageadmin, $headers);
    mail($email, $subjectuser, $messageuser, $headers);
}
?>
```

That way, it doesn't matter if a user goes directly to that page (in GET mode). It will have to go through a post form to actually invoke the **mail()** function. You could also add a simple additional security layer (to avoid posts requests from other sites) by adding a hidden input in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?=md5(date("Y-m-d H"))?>">
```

And then just apply this validation at the start of the writequick.php file:

```
if($_POST['hash'] == md5(date("Y-m-d H"))) {
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: `isset($_POST) && count($_POST)` - summed up in `!empty($_POST)`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //Do stuff here
}
```

This will make sure the user is making a post request before doing anything. Also you will want to verify the variables have values before mailing. Use

```
if(!empty($_POST['variable_key_here'])){
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I like that, but will it still send it if only one field is blank? I don't want people to HAVE to put their contact info if they do not want to.

Answer (score 0):

you can check `$_POST` super global array

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $to      = 'myemailaddress@example.com';
    $subjectadmin = 'CONTACT FORM from My Website';
    $subjectuser = 'Contact Confirmation from My Website';
    $name = $_POST['name'];  
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $comments = $_POST['message'];
    $messageadmin = 'A customer just submitted a form on Your Website.  Here is their message:' . "\n" . "\n" . 'Name:' . '   ' . $name . "\n" . 'Email:' . '   ' . $email . "\n" . 'Phone:' . '   ' . $phone . "\n" . 'Comments:' . '   ' . $comments . "\n";
    $messageuser = 'Hello,' . ' ' . $name . '!' . "\n" . "\n" . 'Thank you for contacting My Website!  We have received your contact form and we will get back to you as soon as we can.' . "\n" . "\n" . 'Just for your records, here is what you submitted to us:' . "\n" . 'Name:' . '  ' . $name . "\n" . 'Email:' . '  ' . $email . "\n" . 'Phone:' . '  ' . $phone . "\n" . 'Comments:' . '  ' . $comments . "\n" . "\n" . 'Thank you for choosing My Website!';
    $headers = 'From: myotheraddress@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subjectadmin, $messageadmin, $headers);
    mail($email, $subjectuser, $messageuser, $headers);
    } else {
      die("Access denied");
    }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to submit contact details on your mail is correct, but
there is no validation in it.

We have many methods to validate forms :

1.You can use CAPTCHA in your form.

2.Client Side Java Script Validations as well as server side PHP validations to check for correct email pattern , empty field , html special characters and all.

Check this link :

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

There are many methods for validations , just google as per your requirement and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<form name="homecontact" action="/admin/formactions/writequick.php?action=mail" method="POST">
</form>
```

in your writequick.php page

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
//place your mail code


}
```